# Modify raw input to look like a bus timetable in specific format using regex?

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++, timetable

I'm trying to figure this out for quite some time already, but can't seem to find the solution that would work at once or in the way I prefer it.

I have an input that looks like this:

```
0430
0500 25 50
0615 34 51
0708 26 43
```

And I need to turn it into this:

```
04:30
05:00,05:25,05:50
06:15,06:34,06:51
07:08,07:26,07:43
```

Since this is only part of the input and manually replacing everything isn't an option, my guess is that the best option is to go with regex.

What needs to be done:

1. Insert colon after the first two ciphers (something like `(^\d{2})` and then doing replace/substitution with `$1:`)
2. Replace each space with comma + first two ciphers + colon.
   My idea was to capture group `(^\d{2}:)` and then replace all spaces with `,$1` (per each line), but I can't seem to find the way to do it.

I use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for doing it, so if you have any advice on how to do it, or where to do it (or even if regex isn't the way to do it, what other way would you recommend) any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I have Notepad++, VS Code on my PC, but for toying around I use regex101.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job with Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\d\d)(\d\d)(?:\h+(\d\d)\h+(\d\d))?`
- Replace with: `$1$2(?3,$1\:$3,$1\:$4:)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (\d\d)        # group 1, 2 digits
  (\d\d)        # group 2, 2 digits
  (?:           # non capture group
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (\d\d)      # group 3, 2 digits
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (\d\d)      # group 4, 2 digits
  )?            # end group, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1
$2              # content of group 2
(?3             # if group 3 exists
  ,$1\:$3           # a comma then content of group 1 and 3
  ,$1\:$4           # a comma then content of group 1 and 4
  :             # else nothing
)               # end conditional
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's very similar to how I'm currently doing it, but what's bothering me about it is that it's not suited for variable lengths. For example, one row might be 0430, another might be 0530 45 55 and another might be 0615 25 30 40 50 55. I thought there would be some recursive way of doing it, since the (h+\d\d) part obviously repeats itself, but when I try to make it that way, it only captures the last matched group, while skipping all in between.

Comment: @DinoBrdar: OK, I see, give me a while ;)

Comment: @DinoBrdar: A workaround: Find `^(\d\d):?(\d\d)((?:,\d\d:\d\d)*)(?:\h+(\d\d))?` Replace `(?1$1\:$2:)$3(?4,$1\:$4:)` and press "Replace all" as many tiimes as needed.

Comment: Another way: Find `^(\d\d):?(\d\d)((?:,\d\d:\d\d)*)(?:\h+(\d\d))?(?:\h+(\d\d))?(?:\h+(\d\d))?(?:\h+(\d\d))?` Replace `(?1$1\:$2:)$3(?4,$1\:$4:)(?5,$1\:$5:)(?6,$1\:$6:)(?7,$1\:$7:)`

Comment: Thanks, that last one does the job in, for me, the most practical way.

Comment: @DinoBrdar: You're welcome, glad it helps. certainly not the cleanest way but it works and I don't find other one.